# Setting value of infopath field by workflow

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have a requirement to set the value of infopath field by workflow.

This link specifies the way to do it but in my case the value in the infopath field does not change on the execution of the workflow.

[This](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/set-value-infopath-form-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm) is the link that I referred to.

Please guide.

Thanx a lot.

Comment: Does the value of the column change in the forms library? Do you reopen the infopath form from the library or ?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake that I was doing was setting the site column as the content type of the Form library.

After removing it from the content type, as per mentioned in the specified link the appropriate result it obtained.